# Convert Date to numeric

Tags: sql-server-2008

How can I convert a date like 'Jan 1 2014 12:00AM' to 20140101?

when the month is less then 10 I need to put a zero.

I tryed with datepart but had problem adding '0' before it.

thank's.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT YEAR(DateField) * 10000 + MONTH(DateField) * 100 + DAY(DateField)
```

To convert it to an integer. Or

```
SELECT convert(char(8), DateField, 112)
```

To convert it to a yyyymmdd string.

Answer (score 1):

If your date is currently a string, you need to convert it to a **real** datetime value first:

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 'Jan 1 2014 12:00AM')
```

(`mon dd yyyy hh:miAM (or PM)` is the SQL Server default format for datetime conversions, so there is no need for a format specifier here.)

---

If it's already a datetime, you can simply use [formatting option 112](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx), which represents `YYYYMMDD`:

```
SELECT CONVERT(nvarchar(8), myDateTimeField, 112)
```

---

(Nesting the two statements as required or converting the string result to a numeric data type is left as an exercise to the reader.)